# Is it possible to cause .NET to convert a custom object to a single value in a JsonResult?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonresult

I have written a class called EncryptedValue.  I have defined operators and ToString to allow it to be used in code as a regular value (int, double, DateTime).  What I want to do is assign a value to this object and include it in my JSON sent back to my page.

Here is my class:

```
public class EncryptedValue<T> {
  public T Value { get; }
  public string Encryted { get; }
  /* Implementation Details */
}
```

Here is my Action:

```
public JsonResult MyAction() {
 EncryptedValue value = 5;
 return Json(new { EncryptedValue: value });
}
```

Here is the JSON I want to produce:

```
{ "EncryptedValue":"TheEncryptedString" }
```

But instead what is produced is:

```
{ "EncryptedValue":{"Encrypted":"TheEncryptedString","Value":2}}
```

Even if I don't put any properties on the class, the JSON looks like:

```
{ "EncryptedValue":{} }
```

Does anyone know how to make the JavaScriptSerializer think that a class is a single value and call ToString() on it?

**UPDATE**

I guess I need to clarify that this is a simplified example.  I have complex types that will be utilizing this class:

```
public class User {
  public EncryptedValue UserId { get; set }
  public string UserName { get; set }
}
```

And I will be writing out a list of users:

```
IList<User> users = GetUsers();
return Json(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to create a anonymous type (or just create it without linq) that contains only the data you want.

Edit:

Does this not accomplish what you are after?

```
        IList<User> userList = GetUsers();

        var users = from user in userList
                    select new
                            {
                                EncryptedValue = user.UserId.Encryted
                            };

        return Json(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of that would be reusable for you, is to provide a custom method on your controller:

```
 protected ActionResult Encrypted<T>(T inputElement)
 {
     Encrypted<T> instance = new Encrypted<T> { Value = inputElement };

     return Json(new { Encrypted = instance.Encrypted });
 }
```

Then you just call this from your controller:

```
public ActionResult Sample()
{
     return Encrypted(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does  this work:

```
return Json(new { EncryptedValue: value.Encrypted} );
```